# How I can add an one object on the others object's layout in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, layout

Hello I'm having 2 objects the one events and the other one categories. I want to put the categories in the layout of the events. i tried but i;m getting an error message

> ```
> Showing layouts/events.html.erb where line #40 raised:
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
> You might have expected an instance of Array.
> The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
> ```

```
  <% for category in @categories %>
      <li><a href="categories/<%=h category.id %>"><%=h category.name %></a>
      <ul>
        <% for subcategory in @subcategories %>
        <% if subcategory.category_id == category.id %>
          <li><a href="/index/category/<%=h subcategory.id %>"><%=h subcategory.name %></a></li>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <% end %>
```

events_controller

```
  def index
    @subcategories = Subcategory.find(:all, :order=>"category_id , name")
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
    @events = Event.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    end
  end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to:category
has_many:events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to:subcategory
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many:subcategories
end
```

my routes

```
  map.root :controller => 'events'
    # Index
  map.connect '/index/', :controller=>'events', :action=>'index'
  map.connect '/index/events/', :controller=>'events', :action=>'index'
  map.connect '/index/category/:id', :controller=>'events', :action=>'showallcategoryposts'
  # Admin
  map.connect '/admin/', :controller=>'events', :action=>'adminindex'
  map.connect '/admin/events/new', :controller=>'events', :action=>'new'
  map.connect '/admin/category/', :controller=>'subcategories', :action=>'index'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

I'm using Instant Rails 2.0
how i can correct my code in order to work?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know where do you get the nil exception? I would imagine it's on @categories instance variable.  If so, you just need to load this instance variable in your controller code.  Post your controller code so it would be easier to see what's going on.

Comment: yes the problem is on <% for category in @categories %>. I have updated the post with the events controller

Answer (score 1):

Apart from whatever problem you have... IMHO, the code looks quite compromising.

Following are the things, which shouldn't be done the way they are currently:

1. Building the URLs manually like href="/index/category/<%=h subcategory.id %>" But I can't say much on it to correct it without knowing which Rails version you are on and without seeing your routes.rb
2. Controller Code is incorrect
3. Model code also needs improvements

Models should look like this:

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :events, :order => "created_at desc"    
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :subcategory    
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :subcategories, :order => "name"    
end
```

EventsController should be like this:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all(:order => "name", :include => {:subcategories => [:events]})

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @categories }
  end
end
```

And your view should look like:

```
<% unless @categories.empty? %>

  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <li>
    <a href="categories/<%= category.id %>"><%=h category.name %></a>
    <ul>
      <% category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
        <li>
          <a href="/index/category/<%=h subcategory.id %>"><%=h subcategory.name %></a>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <% end %>

<% else %>

  Sorry, no events found!

<% end %>
```

I hope this code will fix your bugs as well.
Please try it.

**NOTE: More improvements required in views, depending on your Rails version and your routes.rb ... you should use the path/url methods like  category_path(category) etc.**

Comment: Tried editing and submitting the complete answer but Stackoverflow is taking big time to not detecting the code format. Visit here http://pastie.org/3451709

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your model code.  I wonder if you're taking advantage of ActiveRecord associations.  If you were, you wouldn't need anything more than `@events`.  You could do stuff like:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %><br/>
  <% event.categories.each do |category| %>
    stuff
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Check out [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide.

Comment: i have added the ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure `EventsController#index` is rendering `views/events/index.html.erb`, and `layouts/events.html.erb` knows nothing of `@categories` which is set for use in said rendering.  Where do you render `layouts/events.html.erb`?  Try placing this below your class definition:

```
layout 'events'
```

Also, it is worth checking out what `@categories` is within the controller with a `Rails.logger.debug`.  Is it `nil` there as well?